# how to draw a line in visual studio 2013 c++

Tags: visual-c++, drawing

How to draw a line between two points in visual studio 2013?

and what libraries I should use?

I'm not familiar with the visual c++ but I really need to use it
I looked for it online and all I got is this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, COLORREF color, int thickness) 
{
    HPEN newpen; LPPOINT point = NULL; HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(desktop); newpen = CreatePen(PS_COSMETIC, thickness, color);
    SelectObject(hdc, newpen); MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, point); LineTo(hdc, x2, y2); 
    //Rectangle(hdc,x1,y1,x2,y2); DeleteDC(hdc); DeleteObject(newpen); 
}

void main()
{

    drawLine(1, 1, 2, 2, WHITE_PEN, 0.5);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Did you run this code? It looks like it should work.

Comment: I created a new visual c++ project and pasted the code is a cpp file
and hit f5 and nothing happened I don't know if this how it's done or not btw

Comment: The last two arguments to `drawLine` are a color and an int, but you pass `WHITE_PEN` (which is an index for `GetStockObject`) and 0.5 (which will be truncated to 0). Have you tried passing a color (e.g. `RGB(255,255,255)` and an integer?

Comment: There's far too much wrong here for a StackOverflow answer. Please find some kind of Windows programming guide and study it, then come back when you have specific questions.